# How can I gather all fields with their values except five of them and put them inside new field in the same collection with mongoDB

Tags: mongodb, studio3t

I have a collection that have many documents with too many fields  but I want to gather many of these fields inside  new field called Data, here is an example

```
{
 "_id" : ObjectId("***********"),
  "name" : "1234567890",
  "mobile" : "Test",
.
.
.
.
.
etc
}
```

I want to use updateMany to make all the documents in the collection looks like this

```
{
     "_id" : ObjectId("***********"),
      "name" : "1234567890",
      "mobile" : "Test",
"Data":{
    .
    .
    .
    .
    .
    etc
}
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Option 1(few nested fields): You can do it following way:

```
db.collection.update({},
[
  {
   $project: {
     data: {
      name: "$name",
      mobile: "$mobile"
      }
    }
 }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[playground1](https://mongoplayground.net/p/CdZXZAbfRzu)

Option 2: (If the fields that need to be nested are too many):

```
 db.collection.update({},
 [
  {
   $project: {
    data: "$$ROOT",
    name: 1,
    mobile: 1
 }
 },
 {
  $unset: [
   "data.name",
   "data.mobile"
 ]
 }
],
{
  multi: true
})
```

[playground2](https://mongoplayground.net/p/sQyw0thLgXe)

Comment: but the number of fields I want to gather is huge , I can not list them all, I need a way that I do not have to list manually

Comment: Added option 2 to my answer where the fields that need to be nested are too much  and different number  , but the fields in the document root are the name & mobile only...

Comment: Thank you @R2D2, i accepted your answer